# How to retrieve all charges for a customer in Stripe and dump them into Datatables using ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, datatables, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for my payment gateway and my application is in Classic ASP and I am using DataTables as a table to store all of the charges that a customer has had. What I need to do is retrieve all of the customer metadata and display it in the Datatables table. I know that Stripe will send a response in Json, which is what Datatables uses to populate its table, however there is virtually no documentation for Classic ASP to show to implement this. Here is how Datatables works:

```
$('#sortable').dataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    paging: true,
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    ajax: {
        url: '<ASP PAGE WHERE JSON WILL RETURN>',
        type: 'POST'
      },
    deferRender: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: [0], visible: false, searchable: false },
        { targets: [1], title: 'Office' },
        { targets: [2], title: 'Client' },
        { targets: [3], title: 'Charge Date' },
        { targets: [4], title: 'Charge Amount' },
        { targets: [5], title: 'Last 4 of Card' }
    ],       
    pagingType: 'full_numbers'
});
```

So, if anyone out there has done this, I would really appreciate some kind of insight. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make requests to Stripe's API directly from your frontend code, as you need to use your secret API key in the request.

You need to send the AJAX request to your backend server, which itself will send the request to [retrieve all charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_charges) with the ID of the customer you want in the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_charges-customer) parameter, then relay the response back to your frontend code.

Stripe does not have an official library for Classic ASP, but if you can use .NET, the [Stripe.net](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net) community library is well-maintained and should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you Ywain, that helped me figure it out. I decided to go with PHP.